# How to get use input through ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

For example if i typed 5 then arraylist should take five input 
5 
3
2
3
5
3

```
 import java.util.Scanner*; 
 import java.io.*;
 class Character { 
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 { 
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    // initializing ArrayList 
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) 
        arr.add(i); 

     System.out.println(arr);

     for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++) 
     System.out.print(arr.get(i)+" "); 
  }    
}
```

This code is taking input from use input like if i types 5 then then
   it will take five input form 1 to five i.e
1
2
3
4
5

Comment: You need to ask the user for input again in your `for` loop...You are only asking the user for the number of inputs at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `sc.nextInt()` to get the input and add to the list `arr.add(sc.nextInt());`

```
List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    arr.add(sc.nextInt()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the user for input inside your loop:

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
{  
    int j = sc.nextInt();
    arr.add(j);
}
```